# How to test code that uses system commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

Im writing simple library that check's that mysql server is alive and dependent from results, it do other things. To check connection, I use such code:

```
def check_connection
  result = if @password
    `mysqladmin -u#{@username} -p#{@password} ping`
  else 
    `mysqladmin -u#{@username} ping` 
  end
  parse_result(result)
end
```

How to test this method? I think, I should not connect to mysql server during the test. Only idea I have is to return in one method appropriate string command for ping (depends of password usage) and use it in method like:

```
def check_connection(ping_string)
  `#{ping_string}`
end
```

and in every test only mock this method, thus only this method use command.

What would you do to test it properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can stick with your original code, and approach it like this:

1. Make sure that `parse_result` is unit tested.
2. Mock `check_connection` so that the rest of your tests don't end up triggering a call to `mysqladmin`.

There's a hole in that the connection to mysql itself isn't tested, but I don't think that's a big deal. Testing `ping_string` won't really plug that hole, and given that the call to `mysqladmin` is basically hard coded your risk here is small.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `system` command, instead of the backticks (``), you can stub that out in your tests. So lets say you have this class:

```
class Thing
  def check_connection
    result = system "some command"
    parse_result result
  end
end
```

In your test (and I'll just use rspec syntax for illustration) you could test it like this:

```
it 'should check the connection' do
  thing = Thing.new
  thing.should_receive(:system).and_return "some result"

  thing.check_connection
  # whatever checking you want to make with the parse_result method
end
```

This works because normally the system method gets passed up to `Kernel#system`, which does the real system call. In the test, you are allowing your instance of `Thing` to respond to the system method with some output that you could expect from the real call.